# df.insert results in NAN value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to assign a value to column depending on value from another column:

This is the code i use:

```
Position = pd.Series([])

for i in range(len(df_empty)):
    if df_empty["Rank"][i] > 2:
        Position[i] = int(1)
        
    else:
        Position[i] = int(0)

df_empty.insert(4, "Position", Position)
```

| Return 3M | Rank | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001036 | 3 | NAN |
| -0.031008 | 2 | NAN |
| -0.284040 | 1 | NAN |

I want the result to be:

| Return 3M | Rank | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001036 | 3 | 1 |
| -0.031008 | 2 | 0 |
| -0.284040 | 1 | 0 |

What seems to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

use apply function and pass your function to it

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You want to create `Position` column, If this is OK for you you can do this without `for-loop` and `if...else` and use `numpy.where` like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['Position'] = np.where(df['Rank']>2, 1, 0)
# Or if you want insert
df.insert(loc=0, column='Position_2', value=np.where(df['Rank']>2, 1, 0))
# Or without numpy
df['Position_3'] = (df['Rank'] > 2).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same logic using `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt = pd.DataFrame({"Return 3M":[0.001036, -0.031008, -0.284040], "Rank":[3,2,1]})

dt.assign(Position=dt.apply(lambda x:int(x["Rank"] > 2), axis=1))
```